# Connection of Blogger and Google+

Tags: google-plus, blogger

I've entered to my blog in blogger.com and there was an option to connect it to Google+, where it said that my profile would be replaced by the one on G+, and that I would be able to share my posts with my circles.

I clicked yes, but then it took me to the main blogger page, and everything was the same. My old profile was still there and there wasn't any share button on my posts. What happened?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed only three things that have changed:

- my posts are signed with my first and last name from G+ instead of my screen name from Blogger
- my old profile page is now my G+ profile
- link to my blog appeared in my profile -> about me (but that was there anyway)

Comment: I also get the option of sharing my posts to G+ after I've finished them.